How does the size of the parameter $n$ in $Kyber$ affect the success of lattice reduction of LWE instances?
I'm learning about using lattice reduction to find the secret $s$ of an LWE instance. When testing it on code, I have noticed that when $n$ is 32 or lower, I am able to retrieve $s$ successfully, but when I set $n$ to 64 or higher, it fails. Is there an explanation of why this is the case?

One can solve the LWE instance with small secret $A\mathbf s+\mathbf e\equiv \mathbf t\pmod q$ by finding a row in the span of the matrix
$$m=\begin{pmatrix}A^T & I\\qI & 0\\\end{pmatrix}$$
that is close to the row vector $(\mathbf t,0)$. This is because the row vector $((A\mathbf s)^T,\mathbf s^T)$ lies in the span and the row difference of these two vectors is $(-\mathbf e,\mathbf s)$.
Note that if the entries of $\mathbf e$ and $\mathbf s$ are i.i.d. with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$ then the expected Euclidean size of the difference vector is $\sqrt{(m+n)\sigma^2}$. There are ways to embed this Close Vector Problem as a Short Vector Problem in a comparable lattice.
Looking for the shortest vector in a reduced basis is not a good way to find exceptionally short vectors in large dimensions, but can work in small dimensions. A reduction algorithm will typically come with a guarantee of the maximum length of the shortest vector in the basis. For example, the LLL algorithm with $\delta=0.75$ guarantees that
$$||\mathbf b_1||<2^{(d-1)/4}\Delta(\mathcal L)^{1/d}.$$
In the case of the LWE lattice above, we have $d=m+n$ and $\Delta(\mathcal L)=q^m$ and so
$$||\mathbf b_1||<2^{(m+n-1)/4}q^{m/(m+n)}.$$
Depending on your parameters, we may or may not have $\sqrt{(m+n)\sigma^2}<2^{(m+n-1)/4}q^{m/(m+n)}$ (it becomes increasingly likely as $m+n$ grows. If this inequality holds, we would be asking our reduction algorithm to perform much better than its guarantees. If the reverse is true, we can usually tweak the embedding so that the vector for which we search is included in the basis. It would seem that for your parameters $n=32$, the expected length of the short vector is sufficiently close to the guarantee that we see our solution in the basis, but for $n=64$ it is too small in comparison to the guarantee.
